# How to alter virtual column in snowflake

Tags: database, hash, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, alter

there is a table with virtual column in snowflake like:

```
create table my_tbl(
  key       number, 
  name      varchar(60), 
  owner     varchar(60),
  value     number, 
  check_sum number as hash(key, name, value)
);
```

Could you please advise whether this column is modified with alter statement?

I tried smth like

```
alter table my_tbl modify column check_sum number as hash(key, name, value, owner)
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: You can only change the type of a column to synonymous type, see [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column.html)

Comment: Frankly speaking I'm trying to change number to number with extended list of hash values. So i could see only one way drop and create it agait. Am i right?

Comment: It is a table with virtual column create table my_tbl ( key number, name varchar(60), value number,  check_sum number as hash(key, name, value, owner));

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: syntax error line 1 at position 60 unexpected 'as'.

Answer (score 2):

A quick workaround of the problem I can think of:

```sql
create table my_tbl(
  key       number, 
  name      varchar(60), 
  owner     varchar(60),
  value     number, 
  check_sum number as hash(key, name, value)
);

alter table my_tbl add column check_sum_new number as hash(key, name, value, owner);

alter table my_tbl drop column check_sum;

alter table my_tbl rename column check_sum_new to check_sum;

describe table my_tbl;
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixing my previous answer, as Sanjit notes - you can have a virtual columns in Snowflake.

Although it's not expressly called out in the docs, you can define a virtual column like this:

```sql
create temp table my_derived (x int, my_virtual int as (x*10) );

insert into my_derived(x) values(3);

select * from my_derived;

update my_derived set x=40;

select * from my_derived;
```

(works as expected)

See Sanjit's answer for a solution dropping and adding a new virtual column.